React-native-webview - app crash on file selection from the webview
I am using react native webview to render web content in react native app.but as soon as i try to upload file from the webview it opens the file manager and on selection of file app gets crashed
i have granted the read and write external storage.
error in android studio
E/WebEngage: App has crashed
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document:19 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.xyz.user.debug/com.xyz.user.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

    <WebView
          androidLayerType={'hardware'}
          source={{uri: "https://imgbb.com/#google_vignette"}}
          renderLoading={() => <AnimatedLoader isFullPageLoader={true}/>}
          startInLoadingState={true}
          style={{
            marginTop: 0,
            marginHorizontal: 0,
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            flex:1
          }}
          onNavigationStateChange={(e) => onNavigationStateChange(e)}
          onRenderProcessGone={syntheticEvent => {
            const { nativeEvent } = syntheticEvent;
            console.log(
              'WebView Crashed: ',
              nativeEvent.didCrash,
            );
          }}
          domStorageEnabled={true}
          allowFileAccessFromFileURLs={true}
          allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
          allowFileAccess={true}
          mediaCapturePermissionGrantType={"prompt"}
          androidHardwareAccelerationDisabled={true}
        /> 

I have taken storage permission

im also facing the same error, Did you get the fix ?
